# Python3 module equivalent for GtkSourceView2

Tags: python-3.x, gtksourceview

I'm attempting a port of the abandoned Gedit plugin [codecompletion](https://github.com/nagaozen/gedit-plugin-codecompletion/) to Python 3.

In the original code a Python 2 package is called:

```
import gtksourceview2 as gsv
```

and it is then inherited by a class to, presumably, perform completion:

```
class JSONProvider(gobject.GObject, gsv.CompletionProvider):
    MARK_NAME = 'JSONProviderCompletionMark'

    def __init__(self, plugin):
        gobject.GObject.__init__(self)
        ...
```

I've never used GtkSourceView or its completion functionality, so it's unclear what the inheritance is fulfilling. What is the equivalent `gtksourceview2` (or 3) module in Python 3?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The equivalent would be

```
from gi.repository import GtkSource
```

Comment: Thanks @ptomato. I'm giving it some time but your suggestion imports in Py3 and seems the accepted answer... thing is, why is this arcane knowledge? I could not find your straight-fwd answer via searchengine or SE - at all - at the time of posting.

Comment: [Here's](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/index.html) the documentation; typing "gtksource" there should take you straight to it. I have no idea why it's so ungoogleable.